# How to Normalize &#13; and &#2; while creating xml element in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xslt

I am building xml using `org.w3c.dom.Document` and when creating the text node

```
Document xmlDocument;//This has document 
Node xmlNode = Document xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
xmlNode.appendChild(getDocument().createTextNode(value));
```

if a text value has `"abc\r\n"` then in place of `\r` xml charecter code `"&#13;"` is getting inserted. so when applying xslt transformation on the xml, its giving

```
[Fatal Error] :103:320: Character reference "&#13;" is an invalid XML character.
```

similarly I have issue for `"&#2;"` this charecter, here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[text()[normalize-space()] | @*])]">
        <!-- process element and descendants in mode for debugging -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="debug" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="debug">
        <xsl:message terminate="no">
            Deleting
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
            .
        </xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="debug" />
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Along with I have another issue, after genrating the xml, its removing the namespace declaration from child elements like :

```
<head xmlns:test="">
<body>
   <p-elm xmlns:xyz=""></p-elm>
</body>
```

from `<p-elm>` xml namespace is getting removed.

Any suggestion will be appricated :)

Piece of code applying transformation:

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(getDocument());
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        if(source != null){
            //Templates template = tf.newTemplates(source);
            Templates template = tf.newTemplates(new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(source)));
            serializer = template.newTransformer();
        }else{
            serializer = tf.newTransformer();
        }

        if (outputProperties != null) {
            Iterator iter = outputProperties.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entry entry = (Entry) iter.next();
                serializer.setOutputProperty((String) entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        //XmlUtil.prettyFormat(reader, writer);
        serializer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

here `source` is `xslt path`

Comment: Suggestion: focus on one thing in a question, not on two unrelated things - create two questions. Question: what do you do exactly that causes you to get the &#13; and the error you mention. Do you first write the XML to a file before you invoke xslt? How do you write it to a file (source code).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have updated the piece of code, please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [XML specification (section 2.2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets), `&#2;` is not a valid XML character, but `&#13;` is valid and should not give an error. It means that you're not allowed to put any
`&#2;` character in your XML document even though it is valid to have a `\2` character in Java.

The definition for a valid XML character is:

> Legal characters are tab, **carriage return**, line feed, and the legal
>   characters of Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646.

`&#13;` is a carriage return (same as `&#xD;` in XML or `\r` in Java)

I tried to run your code to see what happens but it doesn't compile and it is missing so many pieces that I cannot easily fix that by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...sorry not able to paste all the code from work space...I went through that XML Specification...for &#2;, I tried to print System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml("&#2;")); its giving me  this charecter ..here STringEscapeUtil is from apache..any help for this

Comment: sorry the equivalent charecters I pasted here is not reflacting

Comment: If you will not mind, I have one question, how to insrtruct xslt not to remove namespaces..